# How to deep link to automation in shortcut app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-universal-links, ios-shortcut

How can an app deep link directly into the automations tab of the shortcuts app?

Below is a user guide with some info about deep linking into the shortcuts app

https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/open-or-search-the-gallery-from-a-url-apd9c112ca23/ios

Running the below code will deep link into the Shortcuts app Gallery

```
let shortcut = URL(string: "shortcuts://gallery")!

UIApplication.shared.open(shortcut, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Automations does not seem to be accessible via deep link : only shortcuts and gallery shortcuts. There is no real utility to access automation using deep link.

Comment: It offers utility if an app is helping users to set up an automation. I see that Apple doesn't explicitly state a way to link into automations, but perhaps there is still a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open URL `shortcuts://automations` can achieve this.

With URL `shortcuts://create-automation`, you can alert an Automation create view after open Shortcuts App.